# Compare IE versions with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am having an issue comparing IE versions with PowerShell.

I have the code below :

```
$CurVersion = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer').Version
    Write-Host "Current Version Of IE is $CurVersion"
IF ($CurVersion -gt "11.*")
            {
              "IE is up to date"    
            }
            ELSE
            {
              "IE needs to be updated"  
            }
```

However, this code doesn't work because $curversion is stored as a string.
9.11.9600.17914
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object

I can remove part of the version number, convert that to int and compare it that way but I'm sure there must be a easier and simpler way.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$CurVersion = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer').Version.Substring(2)
```

Adding .substring(2) should strip out the 9. and make your current script work to a point, The script will run into issues with IE9. If thats not a problem, crack on and stop reading.

For All Versions of IE you could use the code below. This will account for IE 9 version "9.0", IE 10 and 11 ("9.1") and anything else below 9 falls into the else at the end.

```
$CurVersion = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet     Explorer').Version

IF ($CurVersion.StartsWith("9.0"))
{
$CurVersion2 = $CurVersion
}
ElseIF ($CurVersion.StartsWith("9.1"))
{
$CurVersion2 = $CurVersion.Substring(2)
}
Else
{
$CurVersion2 = $CurVersion
}   
Write-Host "Current Version Of IE is $CurVersion2"
IF ($CurVersion2 -gt "11.*")
        {
          "IE is up to date"    
        }
        ELSE
        {
          "IE needs to be updated"  
        }
```